# Kill ( curl ) the process and start new one

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am working on bash script where I need to move 60 files to one folder and curl the api call and wait for another hour to move the 60 files and do the same. so basically I wrote two scripts

```
**script 1 : scan the folder and move one file every min to the destination folder.**
#/bin/bash

#for (( c=1; c<=5; c++ ))
#do  
 #  echo "Welcome $c times"
XMLS="/home/administrator/app/public/2019-02/*"
for f in $XMLS
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  # take action on each file. $f store current file name
#  ls $f
cp $f /home/administrator/app/public/xml/
mv $f /home/administrator/Done/
sleep 60
done
#done
```

**SCRIPT 2: **#/bin/bash****

```
curl http://IP$:3000/upload-video
```

please help me understand if I can use pgrep or any other command to make sure that it triggers every hour.

thank you

Comment: In the second script you can add something like this `date > /path/to/this/script/log/file` and then look in the log file ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, but the usual way to execute a command on a regular schedule is to use `cron`. To terminate it after a specified time there's the `timeout` command. So you could add a cronjob that uses something like `/usr/bin/timeout 59m /usr/bin/curl ...`

Comment: @steeldriver thank you, it did the job…

Comment: OK in that case I will add it as an answer in case it is helpful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to execute a command on a regular schedule is to use cron.  To terminate a command after a specified time there's the `timeout` command.

Putting the two together in a cron job (`crontab -e`):

```
23 * * * *    /usr/bin/timeout 59m /usr/bin/curl ...
```

would run `/usr/bin/curl ...` once every hour (at 23 minutes past the hour), terminating it after 59 minutes if it's still running.